# WPF MVVM: Binding to property of object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I try to display values in my ComboBox using Binding. But I have no idea why isn't it working:

```
<ComboBox Width="476" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Maps.Name}"></ComboBox>
```

Here is my C#:

```
public class Map
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

And main:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Map> Maps { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Maps = mainWindowModel.LoadMapFiles(); //deserializes maps, i checked it, LoadMapFiles() works
    }
}
```

What should I write in ComboBox ItemSource if I want it to display every Map.Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `Maps.Name` is not a valid Binding Path, because `Name` is not a property of the `ObservableCollection<Map>` in `Maps`.

Bind the `ItemsSource` property to the collection property, and set the displayed property by `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Maps}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ... />
```

---

Also make sure that the `Maps` property setter fires a change notification, or make the property read-only:

```
public ObservableCollection<Map> Maps { get; }
```

Comment: Really, that simple? I couldn't find this method whole evening. Thank you so much!